# How to insert an image in the front cover of a report?

Tags: graphics, titles

I'm pretty new in LaTeX and I'm currently writing my BSc Report. 
Does anyone happen to know how I can insert my uni logo on the front cover of my report? 
I'm using

```
\documentclass[final,letterpaper,twoside,11pt]{report}
```

Comment: hey guys i found this and is the best solution for my problem. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation  Thanks for answering though

Answer (score 25):

The `graphicx` package provides `\includegraphics` to include images on the cover or inside the document. And the `titlepage` environment specifies your cover page. (Since this is a recurring problem at institutions, your advisor  probably has examples for such cover pages. But a lot of bad code gets passed around this way.)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \vfill
    {\bfseries\Large
        Performance Report\\
        First Quarter 2011\\
        \vskip2cm
        A. Uthor\\
    }    
    \vfill
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.jpg} % also works with logo.pdf
    \vfill
    \vfill
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The `\vfill`s adjust the vertical spacing. Think about them this way: each `\vfill` will expand vertically *the same amount* until the entire page is filled. Because there are two `\vfill`s at the bottom, title and logo will not be vertically centered but rather shifted towards the top. Using `\vfill` is much simpler than using absolute dimensions and works with all page dimensions. (I still used `\vskip2cm` to specify the distance between title and author, though.)

Comment: I have tried your way but it doesn't work! there is an error about \vskip{2cm}

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the `\vskip`.

Answer (score 23):

There is a package for that on CTAN. [`titlepic`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlepic) redefines the `\maketitle` command to include a picture on your title page, that you provide via the `\titlepic` command:

```
...
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\titlepic{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mypicture.png}}
...
\begin{document}
\maketitle
...
```

Comment: this didn't work for me : `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\titlepic{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{placeholder.pdf}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}`

Comment: For `article` this only works with the `titlepage` option: `\documentclass[titlepage]{article}`

Comment: does not work with `\documentclass{book}` either.

Comment: Works with `book` for me: [titlepic with book](https://sharelatex.gwdg.de/read/ffhrscxjpsdh#b3c331)

Answer (score 8):

If you use the memoir class with the report option (which is supposedly the same as using the report class) you'll get much more control over the title page.

```
\documentclass[report,letterpaper,twoside,11pt,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\author{Totzke Zwack}
\title{The Unspoken Truth}
\date{\today}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{%
  \begin{center}
    \fbox{uni-logo}
  \end{center}}
%
\begin{document}
 \frontmatter
 \maketitle
 \mainmatter
 \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Command \maketitlehookd undefined.`. BTW, I am using `\documentclass{book}`.

Answer (score 3):

I am really not sure if this is so complicated as the no of unanswered questions on this topic looks like.

Just put an image inside your title. Simple :)

You can add a \texttt for formatting the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{./images/ }

\title{
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo.png} Here is my Title
}
\author{Saurabh Adhikary}
.
.
.
\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

Comment: A great solution! This together with commands like `\vspace` allows a lot of control.