# figure between date and bottom of the title page

Tags: floats, page-breaking, titles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert an image in the front cover of a report?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13912/how-to-insert-an-image-in-the-front-cover-of-a-report)

I want to insert a `.eps` figure on the title page of a report. This figure has to be placed after date and then some text below this figure. But I get only title, author, date on the title page. The figure and some text below it comes in next page. Could someone help me to make this figure and text also come on the title page after the date.

Below is the code I used.

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper,twoside] {report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-30em}

\begin{document}
\title{LEARNING LATEX}
\author{rakesh}
\date{\today} 
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics [scale=1, width=2cm,height=2cm] {logo.eps}
\end{figure} 

\begin{center}
dummy text1\\ dummy text2, text3.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents issued in `\date` is stored in `\@date` and could technically be used to do or include whatever. Here's a quick example where you box the `\date` content into something like `\mydate`, which now includes the date `\today`, a figure and some extra text, all bundled into a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper,twoside] {report}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
%\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\begin{document}
\title{LEARNING LATEX}
\author{rakesh}
\newsavebox{\mydate}
\begin{lrbox}{\mydate}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \today \\[2cm]
  \rule{2cm}{2cm} \\[1cm]
  dummy text1 \\ dummy text2, text3.
\end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}
\date{\usebox\mydate}
\maketitle

Here is some text on the following page.
\end{document}
```

Vertical adjustment between the date and the other "date" content is done using the tabular `\\[<len>]` spacing.

Comment: what is this \rule ? and how do i call my logo.eps here ?

Comment: @rakesh: Since I don't have your image (`logo.eps`), I used a rectangular box (2cm x 2cm) to replace it. You can use `\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{logo.eps}` in place of my `\rule{2cm}{2cm}` and it should work as expected.