# How can I add a front cover with an image

Tags: page-breaking, covers

At present I have on my first page the title of the document with the logo on the top left. How can I insert a first page with title and large logo alone, and then small logo in the header on following pages? I have tried a few solutions which have all collided with the present preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=10mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}% http://ctan.org/pkg/braket
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue, urlcolor = blue, citecolor = blue, anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
\newdateformat{mydate}{\twodigit{\THEDAY}{ }\shortmonthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=1em\indent}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{titling}


\pretitle{%
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image.png}\end{flushleft}\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\begin{center}\LARGE\bfseries}
\posttitle{\end{center}}

\date{\today}

\title{Financial Markets}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe the answer of Marcel Köppen here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13912 helps (`\titlepic`).

Comment: I tried this one unsuccessfully.

Comment: Have you seen that you need `\documentclass[titlepage]{article}` for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[headheight=50pt, left=10mm, right=15mm, top=30mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}% http://ctan.org/pkg/braket
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newdateformat{mydate}{\twodigit{\THEDAY}{ }\shortmonthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=1em\indent}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% hyperref NEEDS to be loaded LATE (load cleveref later, if you use it, otherwise hyperref loads last.)
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue, urlcolor = blue, citecolor = blue, anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\pretitle{%
\begin{flushleft}
\end{flushleft}\includegraphics[width=4cm]{tiger}\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\begin{center}\LARGE\bfseries}
\posttitle{\end{center}}
\title{Financial Markets}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[lh]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{tiger}}
\fancyhf[cf]{\thepage}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Note that you will need to adjust `headheight` to accommodate the small version of your logo. To do this, set it to, say, 10pt, compile and read the message from `fancyhdr` telling you how big it needs to be. This information is printed as a warning to the console and log file. Then set it at least that big.

If you use `height=1.5cm`, of course, `50pt` will be large enough. But if you set the graphic to a different height (directly or indirectly), you'll probably need to make an adjustment.

[image: two tigers]